# Получение информации о потоке исполнения через равные промежутки времени python

Tags: python, очередь, multiprocessing, pool

Имеется следующий код:

```
        proc = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cpu)
        proc.map(func, some_data)
```

как мне параллельно с этим пулом запустить ещё один процесс который бы через заданное время получал информацию о том как обстоят дела в каждом из потоков пула?

p.s. костыльно получалось сделать с очередью только результаты получались отдельно по каждому потоку, а не по всем сразу...

Comment: очередь медленней мапа в 10 раз

Comment: Что значит *как обстоят дела*? Что конкретно он должен проверять?

Comment: К примеру в процессе(ах) идет поиск простых чисел и надо через промежуток в n сек проверять на сколько мы продвинулись с этим и скоро процесс уже закончит свою работу. Может быть так что одни процессы уже закончили свою работу а другие только заканчивают и мы хотим дождаться пока некоторые закончат обработку, чтобы прервать выполнение программы тк она уже долго ищет эти самые числа.

Comment: @Вадим задача поиска простых чисел и задача обработки массивов - разные. Сначала массив был - на него ответ есть) поиска простых чисел в вашем примере не вижу. То что тут описанно через менеджер не параллелится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже результат func Вам не важен.

```
    proc = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cpu)
    l = len(some_data)
    i = 0
    for res in proc.imap_unordered(func, some_data):
        i+=1
        print('\r', i*100//l, '%', flush=True, end='')
```

или если результат важен

```
def map_process(p,f,d):
    l = len(d)
    i = 0
    for r in p.imap(f, d):
       i+=1
       print('\r', i*100//l, '%', flush=True, end='')       
       yield r


proc = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cpu)
result = map_process(proc, func, some_data)
```

Или асинхронно и недокументированно

```
proc = multiprocessing.Pool(n_cpu)
jobs = proc.map_async(func, some_data)

while not jobs.ready():
    print('осталось', jobs._number_left)
    jobs.wait(2)
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как мне к примеру получить информацию на сколько процентов закончили свою работу все имеющиеся потоки (сколько данных обработали) в момент когда они ещё работают?

Comment: Или в идеале сделать так чтобы было 3 процесса где в первых двух идет расчет чего-либо, а в третьем мы выводим через n-е время информацию сколько осталось ещё отработать данных каждому из процессов.

Comment: Я добавил пример на основе которого я делаю осн программу только получается что вывод происходит только после того как процесс все рассчитал. То есть вот он начал работать и выводит не 10%..50% а сразу 100% даже при больших нагрузках...

Comment: @Вадим это ж пул процессов, тут не известно какому процессу сколько данных попадет, распределение по мере выполнения. Общий процент я написал выше

Comment: @Вадим тут какраз описанно сколько процент выполнения в момент когда они работают

Comment: Ну это понятно, а если делать ориентируясь по примеру что я дополнил только учесть, что вместо time.sleep будет выполняться реальная работа? И вместо пула будут заданные процессы.

Comment: @Вадим опиши реальную работу: что на входе, что на выходе, есть ли циклы, есть ли рекурсия

Comment: Добавил реальный пример.